# Embedded YouTube videos won't stop playing after navigating away from div

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed

Thanks to the community, and to anyone who takes the time to help.

This probably makes me a pariah around here, but my coding skills are so low-level I bought a one-page template. I've managed to solve a few issues I was having with it, but not this one.

As you'll see here in the Portfolio section (http://www.marketcoremedia.com/port), navigating "next" or "previous" hides the current panel/div and brings up another. Problem is, the template was apparently designed with only one YT embedded video in mind. With several (in my case 6), only the "previous" button on the first video actually pauses the video once it's playing. For all other videos, "previous", "next", and even the "close" button have no effect, and so any video that's playing just keeps on trucking.

I'm pretty sure the answer lies here in this javascript file (http://www.marketcoremedia.com/port/js/boxlayout.js), but for the life of me, I can't seem to get it right, no matter how much I stab in the dark and try out every solution I can find online. Any ideas?

Again, thanks in advance! Stay safe, y'all!

Comment: Just as a comment: Whatever you paid, you probably paid too much. The JavaScript is *really* bad.

Answer (score 0):

It is the following line inside the handler of `$nextWorkItem.on('click', ...)` that creates your problem:

```
$('.youtube-video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
```

It is only taking the first video and pausing it. But you need to pause all of them, so you need to loop over them, like so:

```
$('.youtube-video').each((i, video) => {
    video.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});
```

Same thing goes for the handler of `$previousWorkItem.on('click', ...)` (It's the same call, so just replace it there too)

Edit: Seems like there are more handlers, all with the same error - just replace those too, using the same method.

Comment: Thanks man! Tried it out and updated the js file. Getting there - now the "previous" button works on all videos, but same issue with "next" and "close" buttons, videos won't pause/stop. Any ideas?

Yeah, I'm sure to the trained eye, the code looks awful. From my POV, it's like knowing very little about cars, but needing anything to get you to work. Ya take it for a spin, it *seems* to drive. You open the hood, it *looks* like an engine...

Comment: Please read my full answer, every occurrence of the first code snippet needs to be replaced with the second snippet. To your race car analogy: Think that for every car that is produced, you also build a whole new factory. Would be quite inefficient - why not reuse the old factory. That's kinda like the code provided - a lot of duplicated code. Also in general, it is just written in a way that is very hard to read @RyanJames

Comment: Yeah, I replaced all instances. Didn't quite work. :(

Comment: Well then there are 3 options: 1) I got something wrong 2) You got something wrong 3) The error does not lie in the given file. Remote troubleshooting is not really the purpose of StackOverflow though @RyanJames

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give it a shot, anyway. Much appreciated!